# Trouble keeping focus for mouse wheel scroll

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, mouse

I have a Winform program with a `TabControl` that has two `TabPages` on it, with one `WebBrowser` on each.

I am trying to put focus on the correct browser when I change tabs, so I can use my mouse wheel to scroll. This is the code I use for that:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage1 Then
        WebBrowser1.Focus()
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage2 Then
        WebBrowser2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But this is what I observed.

Keyboard up and down arrow keys always scroll it correctly, even when the mouse wheel does not.
If I go to a different program I have open (in Windows 7), and then come back to this form, most of the time the mouse wheel will scroll after that.

Why all the flaky behavior?

Comment: This may have to do with whether the mouse pointer is directly over the browser control. Can you check what happens when you scroll with the mouse directly over the browser control, and when the mouse is not directly over the browser control?

Comment: Yes, I keep the pointer over the browser control as I attempt to scroll. I try to keep all things equal, and sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.

Comment: Now if I actually click with the mouse inside the browser control, it will allow me to scroll with the wheel immediately.

Comment: I just figured out there is a pattern to this madness. It works twice, it fails twice, it works twice, it fails twice, etc.. So I can change tabs twice and the focus will be put on the appropriate browser, but the next two times it will not do it. Then it starts over. Interesting.

Comment: This is a mouse capture problem, caused by jerking the focus away while the click is being handled.  Adding TabControl1.Capture = False probably will fix it.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Unfortunately, that did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: And yet another observation: taking the focus away from the window and bringing it back toggles the ability to use the mouse wheel to scroll the browser (without first clicking on it). This gets stranger all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the odd behavior but I did a sample project and set some event handlers for GotFocus and LostFocus for the web browser controls.  I'd output some debug text when an event was fired and it didn't always call the LostFocus event and when this would occur the scrolling would not work.

Try setting the focus on Web Broswer Document instead:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Focus()
```

Comment: That actually solved the problem with changing tabs. But now I discovered another - the ability to scroll with a mouse wheel is toggled as focus moves away from the application and back.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions:

- click `settings`
- click `devices`
- select `mouse`
- toggle the option `scroll inactive windows when i hover over them` (maybe a few times and keep checking)

This method works for me.